# TCPDF wrong Arabic Character Display with Sakkal Majalla Font

Tags: tcpdf, arabic

I am using TCPDF for many years. Recently I had to work on Arabic language display. The client wanted SakkalMajalla font (available in Windows/font) and I converted this using TCPDF tool. The conversion process was successful without error.

Now, I am facing a little issue and could not solve it since last 2 months. One of the special characters (called tanween) is placed at the bottom of the preceding character whereas it should be on top.Everything else is working fine but little thing (ٍ
) displayed at wrong place changes the meaning of the word.

يمنع استخدام الهاتف الجوال داخل صالة الاختبار
منعاً باتاً
(I can not upload image as I need 10 reputation points for that, but please notice the little thing on top of this letter تاً. Here, it is displaying properly, but in the pdf it displays at the bottom of the letter.
Is there anyway to edit manually the positioning of this character?

I am searching for the solution for the last 2 months. I event wrote 2 emails to the author of TCPDF Nicolas, but he did not give any response.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the font conversion process *appeared* to work successfully, you should double-check with a font editor (like FontForge) to check that the character is actually encoded correctly in the converted font file.

I have found, after many years of trying to convert all sorts of non-Latin fonts from one format to another, that the most reliable solution for font conversion is this site:

http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf

Comment: I have already tried this online tool. It gives 3 files. I copied all of them to font directory but it displays question marks instead of any text.

Comment: I know how to edit font with font forge but I do not know which file to edit in font forge. The TTF file (that was used to convert) or the .z file which is created by the font converter. Any help in this would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Hi - I just realised that my answer isn't very helpful, because, as you say, the TCPDF conversion process converts to the .z, .ctg.z and .php files. I don't know of any applications that can check those files. Are you 100% sure that the character is correct in the original Windows font? Have you checked that with Font Forge? The only other suggestion I can make is to try and find another conversion process, perhaps one that will convert to OTF files, as I think TCPDF can use those.